# How to solve an equation of functions...?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

so I have this equation:
$f(x)+2f(5-x)=x$, and I need to find $f(1)$.

I tried to substitute $f(x)$ as y and $f(5-x)$ as $m$. There is only one equation, so I can't substitute when I get this:

$y+2m=x$

Can I somehow solve differently?

Comment: Hint:  let $x=1$ and $x=4$.

Answer (score 3):

We can solve it as the following:

First put $x = 1$, we have
$$f(1)+2f(4) = 1$$
where $f(4)$ and $f(1)$ are unknowns so we can't solve it yet.

Then put $x = 4$ in order to get a second equation with the same unknowns, we have
$$f(4)+2f(1) = 4$$

Then, from the second equation, we have $f(4) = 4-2f(1)$. Putting it in the first equation yields
$$f(1)+2(4-2f(1)) = 1 \implies -3f(1)+8=1 \implies f(1) = \frac{7}{3}$$

Comment: wait, why 1 and 4? Where did they come from?

Comment: $f(1)$ is what is asked and in order to find it, we put $x = 1$ first. But when we do that, we also have $f(4)$, which is unknown and not asked. Then since putting $x = 4$ gives $f(4)$ and $f(5-4) = f(1)$, we get the second equation, which is needed to solve the equation system. Notice that just by putting $x = 1$, we can't solve the first equation I have written. We need another, which is derived by putting $x=4$.

Comment: Right. Of course.

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Put $x=1$ and $x=4$ in $$f(x)+2f(5-x)=x.$$

Comment: so like this? f(1)+2f(1)=1...?

Comment: For example, for $x=1$, $f(1)+2f(5-1) = f(1)+2f(4)=1$.